# Multiple build operations failed. Flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio, in-app-purchase

I'm getting the error when opening the Android project from Flutter.

Multiple build operations failed.
Could not create task ':in_app_purchase_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
Could not create task ':path_provider_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
Could not create task ':in_app_purchase_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
this and base files have different roots: E:\MyProject\Easy-irish\build\in_app_purchase_android and C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\in_app_purchase_android-0.3.0+13\android.

Please help me for this.
Thanks in Advance